# Ошибка в файле mysql при распаковке из архива

Tags: mysql, .htaccess

Я попытался перенести web сайт на локальный компьютер в bitrix
при распаковке архива была ошибка:

> Внимание!
>
> Файл `.htaccess` из архива был сохранен в корне сайта под именем `.htaccess.restore`, т.к. он может содержать директивы, недопустимые на данном сервере. В корне сайта создан `.htaccess` по умолчанию. Измените его вручную через FTP.
>
> Операция восстановления системы завершена.

изменять пытался, не помогло.

При попытке открыть сайт выдается следующая ошибка:

> Error! mysql_connect('-', '-', '-')
>
> Access denied for user '******'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> FILE: Z:\home\bitrix.loc\www\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\main.php
>
> LINE: 99
>
> MySQL Query Error: `SELECT L.*, L.LID as ID, L.LID as SITE_ID FROM b_lang L WHERE L.ACTIVE='Y' ORDER BY LENGTH(L.DIR) DESC, L.DOMAIN_LIMITED DESC, SORT []`

Пароль root я не устанавливал, доступ к mysql user есть
При запуске с skip-grant-tables
выдается следующая ошибка

> Error! mysql_select_db(******)
>
> Unknown database '******'
>
> FILE: Z:\home\bitrix.loc\www\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\main.php
>
> LINE: 99
>
> MySQL Query Error: `SELECT L.*, L.LID as ID, L.LID as SITE_ID FROM b_lang L WHERE L.ACTIVE='Y' ORDER BY LENGTH(L.DIR) DESC, L.DOMAIN_LIMITED DESC, SORT [No database selected]`

Буду благодарен за подробный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вы распаковали сайт, но не залили дамп базы данных. О том, как это правильно сделать, у битрикса есть [подробная инструкция](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=2014) - боюсь, это плохой вопрос для ru.SO

Comment: Думаю, вполне нормальный вопрос, особенно если инструкцию здесь продублировать хотя бы в общих чертах.